# How can i add a extra column while importing excel into database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am importing an excelsheet into sql server database there is a column in excel named FlightNumber which is in format AI-2000, AI-2564 etc  I have FlightNumber column in database but there is also another column called FlightId which should have values derived from excel's flightnumber (by removing the first 3 character) For eg:
if the excel has FlightNumber: AI-2032 the FlightId value in db should be 2032. How am i supposed to do this? I am a beginner so you may have to explain along with some code.

This is how i am reading excel :

```
DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
dt7.Load(dr);
DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
DataColumn[] ExcelColumn = new DataColumn[dt7.Columns.Count];

DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
//=================================================
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dt7.Rows.Count; i1++)
 {
   if (dt7.Rows[i1]["PP NO"] == null)
      dt7.Rows[i1]["PP NO"] = 0;
 }
```

also i am using SqlBulkCopy to import along with column mapping

Comment: Can you explain how you set up DataReader?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dtone = new DataTable();
dtone.Columns.Add("idNumber");
dtone.Columns.Add("idOnly", typeof(string), " substring(idNumber, 4, 100)");

dtone.Rows.Add("AI-2000");
dtone.Rows.Add("AE-2001");
dtone.Rows.Add("AF-2002");
dtone.Rows.Add("AH-2003");
```

Here 3rd parameter is `DataColumn.Expression` which specify the default value according to your per-existing columns value, to know more about this [visit here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)